# Regex dot issue (C# .NET Framework 4.0)

Tags: .net, regex

I guess the answer should be obvious but I don't understand

```
Regex reg = new Regex("a\r\n", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
Console.WriteLine(reg.IsMatch(".*a.*")); // writes FALSE
```

Why does this write false ?
I thought that SingleLine allowed the dot to match anything, be it \r, \n, \r\n, \n\r or whatever ?

Comment: I think you are backwards, the pattern should be in the constructor of the `Regex` you have what you want to match there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are backwards, you want to put the pattern in the constructor of the `Regex` rather than what you are trying to match.  Try this:

```
Regex reg = new Regex(".*a.*", RegexOptions.Singleline | RegexOptions.CultureInvariant);
Console.WriteLine(reg.IsMatch("a\r\n")); // writes TRUE
```

Comment: Omg I can't believe it ... that's what I would call forgetting the bigger picture.
Thank you for pointing that out ! I'm going to check it again tomorrow